# Load Table From OLE DB Source and Replace Duplicate Unique Values

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I am designing an SSIS package that will load an 'operational' table from a 'rolling' table. The rolling value can have duplicate values as we want to track all entries but the operational table must have only one row per article/plant combination (String).  What I would like to do is have some way to replace any incoming duplicate values with newest record and then load any remaining totally new row - so if an incoming load contains a 'String' that already exists in the destination, then remove that old record and insert the newer record.  For reference the source table and destination table have the same columns except the rolling table has a 'record #' to give it a primary key.  the fields are:

String (article/plant combo)
Record Date
Qty 
Plant

Comment: Can you provide table structures, since this can be done using SQL command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The design for this will look like below :

You will have 4 tables and 1 view : Source, TMP_Dest (exactly as source with no PK), CHG_Dest(for changes, exactly as destination with no PK), Dest(will have PK), FV_TMP_Dest (this is in case the destination looks different than the source - different field types)

SSIS package :

1.Use ExecuteSQLTask and truncate TMP_Dest because it is just temporary for the extracted data

2. Use ExecuteSQlTask and truncate CHG_Dest because it is just temporary for the extracted data
3. Use one DataFlowTask for loading data from Source to TMP_Dest
4. Define two variables OperationIDInsert=1 and OperationIDUpdate=2 (the values are not important, you can set them as you want) -> you will use them at 5. point below
5. Use another DataFlowTask in which you will have:

   - on the left side OLE DB Source in which you will extract data from the view, ordered by PK (do not forget to set the SortKeyPosition from Advanced Editor for the PK fields)
   - on the right side OLE DB Source in which you will extract data from the Dest ordered by PK (do not forget to set the SortKeyPosition from Advanced Editor for the PK fields)
   - LEFT JOIN between this
   - on the left side ( "insert side") you will have: a derived column in which you will assign as Expression the OperationIDInsert variable AND an OLE DB Destination for inserting the data in CHG_Dest table. In this way, you will insert the data that have to be inserted in the destination table and you know this because you have the OperationIDInsert column.
   - on the right side you will do the same thing but using OperationIDUpdate column
6. You will use ExecuteSQLTask in the ControlFlow and will have an SQL Merge. Based on the PK fields and OperationIDInsert/OperationIDUpdate fields you will either insert the data or update it.

Hope this will help you. Let me know if you need additional info.